# How can you reorder test methods with different attributes so they are together in the code?

Tags: c#, resharper

How can you reorder test methods with different attributes so they are together in the code?

I have an existing File Layout which happily orders the various test methods with the `[TestMethod]` attribute by name using the `Display Name` set to `Test Methods` after `Fields`, and before `All other members`.

BUT the methods with the `[DataTestMethod]` attribute are sorted to the end of the file

And I can't see any option in the R# designer for `Display Name`, apart from `Test Methods`

NOTE: this is will latest R# ... as of "now" this is Ultimate 2018.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might create an entry or update the current one in a pattern which will collect all methods (`Kind`) with particular attributes (`HasAttribute`) using `Or` and `And` Logical Containers:

XAML code

```
<Entry DisplayName="Test Methods">
  <Entry.Match>
    <And>
      <Kind Is="Method" />
      <Or>
        <HasAttribute Name="TestMethod" />
        <HasAttribute Name="DataTestMethod" />
      </Or>
    </And>
  </Entry.Match>
  <Entry.SortBy>
  </Entry.SortBy>
</Entry>
```

Designer View:

[image]